# Getting the "Error: Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: qseqid" when using blast + php

Tags: php, arguments, blast

I'm using a php script, and I need to use blastp to recover some data. This works fine when I run it in command prompt.

```
blastp -query test_query.fa -db notas.fa -task blastp -outfmt "7 qseqid qseq sseqid sseq evalue bitscore" -out musica1.fa
```

But it doesn't work in my script. 
This is my script:

```
$blastp = "C:/wamp/www/SiMiLa/blastp.exe";
$texto = "'7 qseqid qseq sseqid sseq evalue bitscore'";
$cmd = $blastp." -query test_query.fa -db notas.fa -task blastp -outfmt '$texto' -out musica1.fa  2>&1";
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
print_r ($result);
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> USAGE blastp [-h] [-help] [-import_search_strategy filename]
>   [-export_search_strategy filename] [-task task_name] [-db
>   database_name] [-dbsize num_letters] [-gilist filename] [-seqidlist
>   filename] [-negative_gilist filename] [-entrez_query entrez_query]
>   [-db_soft_mask filtering_algorithm] [-db_hard_mask
>   filtering_algorithm] [-subject subject_input_file] [-subject_loc
>   range] [-query input_file] [-out output_file] [-evalue evalue]
>   [-word_size int_value] [-gapopen open_penalty] [-gapextend
>   extend_penalty] [-qcov_hsp_perc float_value] [-max_hsps int_value]
>   [-xdrop_ungap float_value] [-xdrop_gap float_value] [-xdrop_gap_final
>   float_value] [-searchsp int_value] [-sum_stats bool_value] [-seg
>   SEG_options] [-soft_masking soft_masking] [-matrix matrix_name]
>   [-threshold float_value] [-culling_limit int_value]
>   [-best_hit_overhang float_value] [-best_hit_score_edge float_value]
>   [-window_size int_value] [-lcase_masking] [-query_loc range]
>   [-parse_deflines] [-outfmt format] [-show_gis] [-num_descriptions
>   int_value] [-num_alignments int_value] [-line_length line_length]
>   [-html] [-max_target_seqs num_sequences] [-num_threads int_value]
>   [-ungapped] [-remote] [-comp_based_stats compo] [-use_sw_tback]
>   [-version] DESCRIPTION Protein-Protein BLAST 2.2.31+ Use '-help' to
>   print detailed descriptions of command line arguments
>   ======================================================================== Error: Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: qseqid

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error once, but for me, the problem was an incompatible dash character from BLAST's pdf documentation via copy/paste. If someone else has this error and it isn't a syntax error, try replacing any pasted dashes with typed dashes.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing my script to:

```
$blastp = "C:/wamp/www/SiMiLa/blastp.exe";
$texto = "7 qseqid qseq sseqid sseq evalue bitscore";
$cmd = $blastp." -query test_query.fa -db notas.fa -task blastp -outfmt \"7 qseqid qseq sseqid sseq evalue bitscore\" -out musica1.fa  2>&1";
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
print_r ($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and solved in the same was as flyingfinger above. The incorrect'-' had been copy and pasted from some code I got on the internet. deleting the dash and retyping it fixed the issue.